# Can I charge a 18650 Li-ion battery using a transformerless power supply?

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, charger

My question is very simple: can I charge a 18650 Li-ion cell using a transformer-less power supply?

This transformer-less power supply converts AC current to DC current using just a capacitor, a resistor, and a diode; this power supply has only three components.

Will it be safe and ensure a good life span for my single 18650 cell?

Answer (score 2):

No it will not, you have to have a circuit that charges and monitors voltage, current and temperature within the batteries specification. You also need to have at least one overcurrent protection circuit, preferably with a fuse as well.

Comment: thanks dear confirming me.I think i have to use different type chemistry of cell. because now project power supply and cell protection module cost will reach more than project itself. Even It has no space at all. I am again where I had started.

Answer (score 1):

No, you need a proper Li-ion battery charger to charge such batteries safely, one that uses the CC/CV algorithm, limits the charging current, and limits the charging end voltage to what is specified for the battery.

Don't try charging them with a generic power supply; using such a supply on its own won't work well, and could be dangerous.

Comment: thanks dear for confirming me.I think i have to use different type chemistry of cell. because now project power supply and cell protection module cost will reach more than project itself. Even It has no space at all. I am again where I had started.